# How to edit the Read-Only tooltip of Monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

How can I edit the tooltip that shows up when trying to edit code in the Monaco editor with read-only set on true?

[image: Picture of the tooltip I am talking about]

On another note what is the function of the domReadOnly option in comparison to the readOnly option?

> Should the textarea used for input use the DOM readonly attribute. Defaults to false.

I checked the behavior of setting the readOnly and domReadOnly options on true where latter seemingly sets the editor on readOnly without rendering the tooltip. However I couldn't find any info on changing style and content of the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `domReadOnly: true`

```
var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: "// First line\nfunction hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}\n// Last line",
    language: 'javascript',

    lineNumbers: 'off',
    roundedSelection: false,
    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
    readOnly: true,
    domReadOnly: true,
    theme: 'vs-dark',
    onDidAttemptReadOnlyEdit: () => false
});
```